# Passing variables between two running services in Node

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, url

I have a variable which needs to be passed on to another running service.
For example, I have an id in webpage https://www.example.com/send_id . I need to get the id that webpage has so that I can use it in https://www.example1234.com/receive. I want to do this in node-express. Is there any way I can pass the variable securely?

Comment: SSH tunnel, https whatever...

Comment: you can use pubsub